# How to make the columns in VBscript fixed

Tags: vbscript

I'm a beginner in VBscript and I got a script which obtains disk space usage of local drives. However, when some columns would contain long numeric value, some adjacent columns and even values are moving to the right and thus makes the output disorganized. I already

Please see below the contents of the script:

```
Option Explicit

const strComputer = "."
const strReport = "F:\dba_scripts\diskspace.txt"


Dim objWMIService, objItem, colItems
Dim strDriveType, strDiskSize, txt

Set objWMIService = GetObject("winmgmts:\\" & strComputer & "\root\cimv2")
Set colItems = objWMIService.ExecQuery("Select * from Win32_LogicalDisk WHERE DriveType=3")
txt = "DRIVE" & vbtab & vbtab & "SIZE" & vbtab & vbtab & "USED" & vbtab & vbtab & "FREE" & vbtab & vbtab & "FREE(%)" & vbcrlf
For Each objItem in colItems

    DIM pctFreeSpace,strFreeSpace,strusedSpace

    pctFreeSpace = INT((objItem.FreeSpace / objItem.Size) * 1000)/10
    strDiskSize = round((objItem.Size /1073741824),1) & " GB"
    strFreeSpace = round((objItem.FreeSpace /1073741824),1) & " GB"
    strUsedSpace = round(((objItem.Size-objItem.FreeSpace)/1073741824),1) & " GB"
    txt = txt & objItem.Name & vbtab & vbtab & strDiskSize & vbtab & vbtab & strUsedSpace & vbTab & vbtab & strFreeSpace & vbtab & vbtab & pctFreeSpace & vbcrlf

Next

writeTextFile txt,strReport
wscript.echo "Report written to " & strReport & vbcrlf & vbcrlf & txt

' Procedure to write output to a text file
private sub writeTextFile(byval txt,byval strTextFilePath)
    Dim objFSO,objTextFile

    set objFSO = createobject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

    set objTextFile = objFSO.CreateTextFile(strTextFilePath)

    objTextFile.Write(txt)

    objTextFile.Close
    SET objTextFile = nothing
end sub
```

The output file looks OK but when I send/email it using the free bmail, the results are disorganized (meaning some columns and values moved to the right.

My question is are there ways to make the columns and values results fixed ( meaning no columns and values are moving to the right )?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
Function RightJustified(ColumnValue, ColumnWidth)
   RightJustified = Space(ColumnWidth - Len(ColumnValue)) & ColumnValue
End Function
```

Usage example:

```
output = output & _
         RightJustified(strDiskSize, 15) & _
         RightJustified(strUsedSpace, 15) & _
         RightJustified(strFreeSpace, 15) & _
         RightJustified(pctFreeSpace, 15) & _
         vbCrLf
```

**EDIT**

Add the **RightJustified** function to your script.

Then, replace this line of your code:

```
txt = txt & objItem.Name & vbtab & vbtab & strDiskSize & vbtab & vbtab & strUsedSpace & vbTab & vbtab & strFreeSpace & vbtab & vbtab & pctFreeSpace & vbcrlf
```

with:

```
txt = txt & objItem.Name & _
      RightJustified(strDiskSize, 15) & _
      RightJustified(strUsedSpace, 15) & _
      RightJustified(strFreeSpace, 15) & _
      RightJustified(pctFreeSpace, 15) & _
      vbCrLf
```

---

### **EDIT 2**

I added the RightJustified function at the bottom of your script, and then called it within your loop to format the columns. I also used it on the column headers. Below is the script and at the bottom is the output on my machine.

```
Option Explicit

const strComputer = "."
const strReport = "F:\dba_scripts\diskspace.txt"


Dim objWMIService, objItem, colItems
Dim strDriveType, strDiskSize, txt

Set objWMIService = GetObject("winmgmts:\\" & strComputer & "\root\cimv2")
Set colItems = objWMIService.ExecQuery("Select * from Win32_LogicalDisk WHERE DriveType=3")

txt = RightJustified("DRIVE", 10) & _
      RightJustified("SIZE", 15) & _
      RightJustified("USED", 15) & _
      RightJustified("FREE", 15) & _
      RightJustified("FREE(%)", 15) & _
      vbCrLf

For Each objItem in colItems

    DIM pctFreeSpace,strFreeSpace,strusedSpace

    pctFreeSpace = INT((objItem.FreeSpace / objItem.Size) * 1000)/10
    strDiskSize = round((objItem.Size /1073741824),1) & " GB"
    strFreeSpace = round((objItem.FreeSpace /1073741824),1) & " GB"
    strUsedSpace = round(((objItem.Size-objItem.FreeSpace)/1073741824),1) & " GB"

    txt = txt & _
      RightJustified(objItem.Name, 10) & _
      RightJustified(strDiskSize, 15) & _
      RightJustified(strUsedSpace, 15) & _
      RightJustified(strFreeSpace, 15) & _
      RightJustified(pctFreeSpace, 15) & _
      vbCrLf
Next

writeTextFile txt,strReport
wscript.echo "Report written to " & strReport & vbcrlf & vbcrlf & txt

' Procedure to write output to a text file
Sub writeTextFile(byval txt,byval strTextFilePath)
    Dim objFSO,objTextFile
    set objFSO = createobject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    set objTextFile = objFSO.CreateTextFile(strTextFilePath)
    objTextFile.Write(txt)
    objTextFile.Close
    Set objTextFile = nothing
End Sub

Function RightJustified(ColumnValue, ColumnWidth)
   RightJustified = Space(ColumnWidth - Len(ColumnValue)) & ColumnValue
End Function
```

Output produced:

```
 DRIVE           SIZE           USED           FREE        FREE(%)
    C:        48.4 GB        40.6 GB         7.8 GB           16.1
    D:       100.6 GB        56.8 GB        43.8 GB           43.5
```

Comment: +1 as long as the E-mail is sent and received using a fixed-width font.

Comment: Good point. Assuming the email is sent as plaintext, I think most readers will display it with a fixed-width font.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. How do I implement the function in the script I provided?

Comment: I've tested sending the output as body of message, but the output is not properly displayed (meaning there are still columns and values not moving to the right )

Comment: the output looks like this:

DRIVE  SIZE  USED  FREE  FREE(%)
C:          16 GB        11.2 GB         4.8 GB           29.7
D:        51.8 GB         2.5 GB        49.3 GB             95
E:       279.4 GB       117.8 GB       161.6 GB           57.8
F:         201 GB        35.1 GB       165.9 GB           82.5
G:         151 GB        50.4 GB       100.6 GB           66.6
H:         100 GB         3.3 GB        96.7 GB           96.6
I:         101 GB         2.2 GB        98.8 GB           97.8
J:       534.6 GB       400.6 GB         134 GB             25

Comment: Sorry for posting the output , i don't know it's not being displayed "as is". I tested it but the columns are not aligned so I just adjusted the values which I don't think is not a good way. Is there a way to include the columns as part of the rightjustified function?

Comment: Thanks. Is it now working in some servers. However, in one server I encountered "VBScript runtime error: Invalid use of Null: 'round' ". I noticed one drive has filesystem of RAW and is "not ready". This could be the cause of the error though I'm not so sure. If I'm right, is there a way to include in the script that this kind of drive should not be scanned? THere is also one 2 servers that run on Windows NT 4 which does not have cscript to run vbscript. Is there an alternative tool to rn vbscript in Windows NT?

Comment: I happen to have one remaining NT Server at work, so I checked and it does have Windows Script Host 5.6 installed (which includes WSCRIPT.EXE and CSCRIPT.EXE). I think you may need to have at least IE4 installed to get it.

Comment: Check the objItem.FileSystem property to make sure it is not RAW. Or, maybe it would be better to check that it is FAT, FAT32, or NTFS.

Answer (score 1):

You could write out a table using HTML. This should work in an email.